# QR Code for Android phones to subscribe to a public calendar - how to create?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, qr-code, icalendar

I am the tech guy for my choir, and I have created a public calendar for our rehearsals.

Since not all my colleagues are tech-savvy, I want to distribute a QR Code during the rehearsal. The idea is that one scans the QR Code and the calendar is **subscribed**, i.e. any changes in the calendar gets automatically pushed to the phones of the members.

For ios, it works out of the box.

I use this URL:

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/gemischter.chor.zuerich%40gmail.com/public/basic.ics

I haven't managed to get it to work for Android phones. During my testing sessions the calendar gets **imported** (a one-off action where the rehearsals get imported into the person's calendar, with no pushing).

I have tried the following URL:

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0?cid=Z2VtaXNjaHRlci5jaG9yLnp1ZXJpY2hAZ21haWwuY29t

but no bananas.

I have tried to search the google documentation, and am desperate to find an authoritative answer.

Comment: By "syncing" you mean updating if something changes on server side? Because a real two-way sync will very fast lead to collisions in case multiple clients use it. For updating such calendars clients usually poll for changes in a specified frequency (usually hours or days). So it depends on the used client.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited the question to say 'pushed' instead of 'synced'. I am talking about a subscription. And yes, two way-syncing is a nightmare :-)